# SQLite database on FireDAC engine not respecting rollback

Tags: sqlite, delphi, transactions, rollback, firedac

I have a Data Access Object (DAO) in a Delphi (Delphi 10.1 Berlin) application. I create the connection with the SQLite database, select some data (Simple select clause) and then execute an update clause, using the method ExecSQL() of TFDQuery component. The data in database is **not changed**.

Then, I execute the rollback() method in the connection. The data in database is **not changed** yet.

So, I execute the close() method in the connection. The data in database **is changed**.

I don't know if this is the expected behavior of FireDAC and SQLite, but I think it should not be.

Some code:

```
FFDConnection                  := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
FFDConnection.Params.Database  := 'database.db3';
FFDConnection.Params.UserName  := '';
FFDConnection.Params.Password  := '';
FFDConnection.Params.DriverID  := 'SQLite';
FFDConnection.Open();

FFDQuery            := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
FFDQuery.Connection := FFDConnection;

FFDConnection.StartTransaction();
// ... Some update code ...
FFDConnection.Rollback();
FFDConnection.Close();
FFDConnection.Free();
```

After the `FFDConnection.Rollback();` but before `FFDConnection.Close();` the data in database is still not changed. After `FFDConnection.Close();` the data in database is changed.

Is this a problem of SQLite?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**EDIT 1:** The problem is that I was not creating the `TFDTransaction` for my connection beacuse I thought that the creation was implicit. I feel so dumb.

Comment: No, it is not. Using implicit connection transaction is fine. Though I'm having trouble to understand your problem. Haven't you started more than one transaction? That connection closing commit is most probably caused by the default setting of the `TFDTxOptions.DisconnectAction` of your connection, but there seems to be more than one transaction (code we cannot see). Inner is rolled back and outer commited (by that default connection closing action). But this is only guess. In any case, code like that makes little sense to me, you do some updates that you later rollback no matter what. Why?

Comment: The problem is solved. I created a `TFDTransaction` object and used it in my connection. The problem was that after I changed some data, called rollback and closed connection, the changes is commited, and not rolled back.

Comment: That should not happen. Only if you started inner transaction. There should be always implicit transaction assigned for you in the connection object. It sounds like a bug for me. Try to re-read what I wrote, maybe that's your case. If it's not, it should not happen.